# including a php script makes post thumbnails disappear if placed before the loop

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using a php script to fetch some external data for display on my wordpress site. This have worked flawlessly for a year now, but when I had to rearrange som elements on the front page the post thumbnails in my loop suddenly stopped showing.

After some research I've found out that if I include my php script **after** the loop the post thumbnails appear, but if it's included **before** the loop the post thumbnails mystically dissapears.

The PHP-log gives me no hint, and Wordpress simply generates NO html in the post thumbnail block when the script is included before the loop.

Anyone have any ideas why this happen? And how I can get around it?

(PS. The reason I need the script included before the loop is a matter of styling/css. I guess I could do some CSS-hacking to make it work after the loop, but I would rather find out what causes the problem.)

Here's so code:

My index.php where the post thumbnail should appear(**this does NOT work**):

```
<!-- ### This includes the php script, and works if it's placed bellow the loop/#leftcontent ### -->
<div id="rightcontent">
    <?php include("rightcontentreleases.php"); ?>
</div>



<!-- ### Standard wordpress loop ### -->
<div id="leftcontent">

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

           <div class="post">

                    <h2 class="posttitle"><a 
                        href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" 
                        rel="bookmark" 
                        title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>


                        <!-- ### The post thumbnail ### -->
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" ><?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) {the_post_thumbnail();}?></a>



                    <div class="entry">
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?><a class="readmore" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Read more</a>
                    </div>

            </div><!-- .post -->

 <?php endwhile; else: ?><p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p><?php endif; ?>

</div><!-- #leftcontent -->
```

**This works**:

```
<!-- ### Standard wordpress loop ### -->
    <div id="leftcontent">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

               <div class="post">

                        <h2 class="posttitle"><a 
                            href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" 
                            rel="bookmark" 
                            title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>


                            <!-- ### The post thumbnail ### -->
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" ><?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) {the_post_thumbnail();}?></a>



                        <div class="entry">
                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?><a class="readmore" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Read more</a>
                        </div>

                </div><!-- .post -->

     <?php endwhile; else: ?><p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p><?php endif; ?>

    </div><!-- #leftcontent -->



    <!-- ### This includes the php script, and works if placed after the loop like this ### -->
    <div id="rightcontent">
        <?php include("rightcontentreleases.php"); ?>
    </div>
```

The external script simply loops through an external database, and showing some standard html:

```
<?php // this script connects to the external database, and defines some functions fetching the data ?>
<?php include_once("tigernet.php"); tigernetmysql(); get3upcoming(); ?>


<?php if (mysql_fetch_assoc($resultupcoming) > 0): ?>
<div class="rightcontentreleases" id="upcomingreleases">
<h2 class="head">Upcoming Releases</h2>

<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultupcoming)) { ?>
<div class="onelatestrelease">
    <a href="<?php bloginfo( 'wpurl' ); ?>/releases"><img class="albumartwork" src="http://media.tigernet.no/images/item/full/<?= $row["code"] ?>.jpg" /></a>
    <h2 class="artist"><?= $row["artist"] ?></h2><br/>
    <h3 class="title"><?= $row["title"] ?></h3><br/>
    <?php if (isset($row['url'])): ?><div class="soundcloudplayer_right">
            <object height='18'><param name='movie'value='http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=<?= $row['url'] ?>&auto_play=false&player_type=tiny&show_duration=false&show_user=false&show_playcount=false&font=Arial&color=92140e'>
                                <param name='allowscriptaccess' value='always'> 
                                <param name='wmode' value='transparent'>
                                <embed wmode='transparent' allowscriptaccess='always' height='18' src='http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=<?= $row['url'] ?>&auto_play=false&player_type=tiny&show_duration=false&show_user=false&show_playcount=false&font=Arial&color=92140e' type='application/x-shockwave-flash'>
                                </object>
    </div><?php endif; ?>
</div><!-- .onelatestrelease -->
<?php } ?>

</div><!-- #latestreleases -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: could you clarify where the external script include is placed when it works / when it doesn't work ?

Comment: Edited and clarified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some way, your `rightcontentreleases.php` must be messing up the database object that answers to `have_posts()`. The right thing to do would be to look into `have_posts()` and verify why and where this happens.

Or you can employ a workaround:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<!-- ### Standard wordpress loop ### -->';
<div id="leftcontent">
...
</div><!-- #leftcontent -->
<?php $leftContent = ob_get_clean(); ?>
<div id="rightcontent">
<?php include("rightcontentreleases.php"); ?>
</div>
<?php print $leftContent; unset($leftContent); ?>
```

This basically executes the standard loop **saving the output** into `$leftContent`. So, you are in the situation you described with "everything works".

Then you execute the rightcontent, which also will work and will output the rightcontent before anything else.

Finally, you output `$leftContent`, which at this point is just inert HTML that can't mess with anything.

But remember, this is a **workaround**. It will work in simple setups. More complicated setups will still not work, and will require you investigate where the real trouble is.

I assume that the reason you don't get thumbnails is that the function `have_posts()` suddenly returns FALSE if it gets called after the new content block. If it triggers an error instead,  you will have to look into your application's logging, and if you find no error, understand why this error goes unreported. But for now let's assume there's no error, and that you just need to quickly find where things go awry.

To do that, you can try a different hack, by including a line like this in your code

```
 have_posts() or die("SOMETHING JUST CLEARED MY POSTS!");
```

...we know that if you put it at the beginning it will not trigger, and the posts will get output. We also know that if you invert the two blocks, that line will trigger.

So by moving that line inside the code generating the content on the right, starting at the top, you will find where it triggers. The operation immediately before evidently did *something* to your post flags (maybe by closing a DB connection, or things like that). Once you discover what it did, you can start planning on how to circumvent the issue.